# Access denied when trying to deploy jars to a Nexus 3 repository using Maven but able to download dependencies

Tags: maven, deployment, jar, nexus

I have installed Nexus 3 on a server with the following repositories:

First repo:

```
Name: maven-central, 
Type: proxy, 
Layout policy: Permissive, 
URL: http://ip:port/nexus/repository/maven-central/,
Remote storage: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Second repo:

```
Name: own,
Type: hosted,
Version policy: Mixed,
Layout policy: Permissive,
URL: http://ip:port/nexus/repository/own/
```

Repo group:

```
Name: whatever,
Format: maven2,
Type: group,
Members: maven-central, own
URL: http://ip:port/nexus/repository/whatever/
```

I have installed the SSL certificates for the following repos: repo1.maven.org and for repo.maven.apache.org.

The settings.xml has the following structure:

```
    <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven-repository</id>
                <url>http://ip:port/nexus/repository/whatever/</url>
                <snapshots>    
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>   
            </repository>
         </repositories>

         <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                        <id>maven-repository-plugin</id>
                        <name>maven-repository-plugin</name>
                        <url>http://ip:port/nexus/repository/whatever/</url>
                        <releases>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                            <updatePolicy>interval:15</updatePolicy>
                            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

</profiles> 

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>maven-repository</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>**</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The problem is that I am able to use this settings.xml file to download project dependencies but I am not able to deploy files using Maven because I get the following error:

`Failed to deploy artifacts groupId:artifactId:version:jar:version from/to remote-repository(http://ip:port/nexus/repository/whatever): Access denied to: http://ip:port/nexus/repository/whatever/groupId/artifactId/...`,

when running the following deploy command:

```
 deploy:deploy-file   
-Durl=http://ip:port/nexus/repository/own/
-DgeneratePom=false   
-DgroupId=groupId  
-DartifactId=artifactId 
-Dversion=version  
-Dpackaging=jar   
-Dfile=name.jar
```

Is there anything I can do? I have tried changing the repositories to use the hosted repo(own) instead of the group, I have tried adding mirrors in the settings.xml file.

I have to mention that the user is the default admin which has the default roles(All).

I was thinking that it might be a problem with the SSL inbound certificates, but in Nexus 3 I don't know how to disable the check. Also there is no possibility at the moment to upload the jars manually.

Edit: I also tried adding mirrors, but when I add the mirrors the download stops working. 
2nd edit: With HTTP I was able to upload files(using CURL)

Comment: Did you add the `<distributionManagement>`tag to your pom?

Comment: @Christian I am not trying to deploy a jar created by myself. I am trying to deploy a random jar, because Nexus 3 doesn't offer a possibility for uploading jars manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the question is old, I remember that I had 2 problems.

I have fixed them by:

1. Adding and setting the right proxy and the right non-proxy hosts.
2. Adding the right trust store (and the right certificate).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "-DrepositoryId=someid" to the deploy-file goal, where "someid" is the ID of a server section in your settings.xml file that has the credentials needed for deployment.

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>someid</id>
      <username>deployment</username>
      <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

Comment: I have already tried that but still not working. It gives me the same error message.

Comment: Check the nexus request.log, if login credentials are being sent you'll see the user ID in the third column.  If the third column contains "-" then login credentials are not being sent, and there is something wrong with your maven setup.